# Node js code using promises

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I'm very new to the Q library.

I'd like to rewrite following code using promises.

The code bellow is **Sync**

```
var items = getItems();
var relatedItems = processItems(items)
saveRelatedItems(relatedItems)
markItemsAsProcessed(items)
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here is my code for now

```
getItems()
.then(processItems)
.then(saveRelatedItems)
.fail(ProcessError)
```

Now I need to mark my items for the `getItems()` as processed. And I also need to call `markItemsAsProcessed` only after `saveRelatedItems()` call is completed.

How can I make this flow using promises?

Comment: You need to understand what asynchrony means.  If your code is synchronous, that means you don't have any non-CPU-bound (async) work.  (or it means that your code is completely broken).

Comment: So you're asking how to make a function asynchronous, without telling us anything about the function?

Comment: I'm not asking about how to make this functions async. I just wondering how can I create the flow that I described

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qvalue

Comment: The fetched `items` are passed through to `processItems`, so `processItems` can make them available to `saveRelatedItems`, and `saveRelatedItems` can make them available to `markItemsAsProcessed`. If you need to pass more than just `items` down the chain then do so with an "accumulator object", ie a javascript object which, at each stage of the chain, is received-augmented-forwarded down the chain. Thus you can make any data from any stage available to any later stage.

Comment: I just found an article that explains everything pretty well https://engineering.linkedin.com/javascript/journey-promises-land

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a promise for an existing value, use `Q(value)`.

**EDIT**: You can use `.thenResolve()` to inject an existing value into a promise chain:

```
var value = ...;
value.then(processItems)
    .then(saveRelatedItems)
    .thenResolve(value)
    .then(markItemsAsProcessed)‌​
    .fail(ProcessError).
```

Comment: let's say I will `getItems().then(processItems).then(saveRelatedItems).then(markItemsAsProcessed).fail(ProcessError)`. How can I make values returned from `getItems()` available in my very last `then()`?